# How do I insert a Google Document into a Google Site using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-docs, google-apps-script, google-sites

Using Google Apps Script, how can I accomplish the same as "Insert" -> "Document" within the Google Sites Editor?

Using GAS, I can obtain the URL and/or the ID of a document, but I cannot create the equivalent of an embedded Google Document within a Google Site Page.

I have been able to insert an `<iframe>`, but that assumes that the document has been published as a web-document.

I can copy the html from an existing page and using `replace()` substitute a different ID, but that only appears to work if the original page gadget has borders and title turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you mentioned should work. Have a 'template' page with a dummy Google Document inserted in it and then use Apps Script to replace the dummy with your document. Can you put in some code around the replace you have.

Comment: It does work, that is, I can copy an existing page that I've set-up using the UI, but it is very fragile. I can only make it work if the original has the borders and title turned on. It appears as if the setHtmlContent() method is still filtering code that comes from getHtmlContent() (as per [Issue #572](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=572))

Comment: @OnnoBenschop you could also just replace /edit at the end of your google doc URL with /export?format=html, and embed an iframe of that link into your google website, or better yet make a fetch request to that website when the page loads (if google sites will allow you), and when you get the contents write the text result to a div on the page and it should render as HTML (meaning with the images), or just to /export?format=txt if you have html tags embedded in the google doc you want to share